# Wrong min value for a geo tif file

Tags: gdal, qgis, geotiff, rasterio

I am working on pre-processing a few geo-tif files. I want to obtain the minimum value for my raster image. My OS is Linux and Rasterio version 1.3.3. When I run my script in a conda environment, I realized that the minimum value is given as zero which is incorrect.

I am using the following code:

```
with rasterio.open(file) as tif_input_obj:
    tif_data = tif_input_obj.read()
    print(tif_data.min())
```

I tried running the same lines of code by typing python in my conda environment. This time the minimum value was obtained correctly. I have also tried gdal and faced the same problem.

has anyone faced this issue before?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you use `gdalinfo -stats` it will create or read from an `.xml` sidecar file. If the geotiff is later updated, the sidecar file may get out of sync, and therefore max/min values will be out of date. I think the same goes for the GDAL method `GetStatistics()`. But I can't imagine how your code would deliver the wrong answer.

Comment: Do you account for the nodata value, which is perhaps zero?

Comment: @RutgerKassies Thank you. Yes, the problem was related to nodata value.

Comment: @RobertDavy Thank you. The problem was related to nodata value which had been set to zero.